# Simple Wcf service result in no endpoint exception

Tags: c#, wcf

I am just learning wcf and I tried creating a WCF service but I keep getting this exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no
>    endpoint listening at `http://localhost:8733/Person/` that could accept the messa
>   ge. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerExcept
>   ion, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to conne
>   ct to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection c
>   ould be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8733

I started out by creating a WCF Service Library.I have defined my service contract and data Contract here.And configured the endpoint witch look like this:

```
<service name="SelfHosting.PersonContract">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SelfHosting.IPersonContract">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Person/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

These two endpoints were already added I just configured them to my needs.I am not sure what the mex endpoint is used for so I am hopping someone can tell me.

I then created a console application and I added a reference to the service.I have initialized an instance of the service and then I tryed calling it:

```
static PersonContractClient client = new PersonContractClient();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var persons = client.GetPersons();
        foreach (var personData in persons)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(personData.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(personData.Email);
        }
    }
```

I have not set any endpoints on the client because from what I know they are automaticly added when you add a reference to the service.This was added after I adde the reference:

```
 <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Person/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPersonContract" contract="PersonNamespace.IPersonContract"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IPersonContract" />
```

My solution also contains another project that has the data, which I get using Entity Framework. I do not know if this is relevant to the problem.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Mex is used to send the schema, so you can use a code generator like svcutil or WcfTestClient.exe. You would take this out for a production system.

Comment: Also, how are you hosting the HTTP service? IIS or through a console app, or Windows Service?

Comment: To me the, the exception is saying that the service is down. Have you deployed it, or are you running it standalone when you run or client code?

Comment: through a console app

Comment: Can your browse to http://localhost:8733/Person/ ?

Comment: No it seems I can not

Comment: Are you running VS in Administration Mode? The Console App needs to run in Admin mode to be able to create the http endpoint.

Comment: yes I set visual studio to always run in admin mode

Comment: Can you send the code for the console app you are running and hosting the wcf service in?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when i tried to create a duplex wcf communication using self host in a console application. Following this example http://adamprescott.net/2012/08/15/a-simple-wcf-service-callback-example/ made it clear. It is common to get the error

"Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8733/Person/ that could accept the messa ge. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerExcept ion, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to conne ct to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection c ould be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8733"

Before attempting to discover the service reference in the client console app, you need to start up the executable(.exe) of the service by right click the .exe in the folder location > copy the uri in the baseaddress in the service app.config and paste in the add service reference dialog then click ok... that fixed it. I hope this helps others, since the question is a bit old.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'localhost' in the url use the ip address of the endpoint.